# Unable to make field public java.lang.String blockchain.Block.hash accessible: module noobChain does not "exports blockchain" to module gson

Tags: java, gson, blockchain

I am trying to run my java blockchain program and print the output in JSON (using gson library).

```
package blockchain;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.*;
import java.sql.Time;

public class NoobChain {
        public static ArrayList<Block> blockchain = new ArrayList<Block>(); 
        //main method
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            blockchain.add(new Block("Hi im the first block", "0"));        
            blockchain.add(new Block("Yo im the second block",blockchain.get(blockchain.size()-1).hash)); 
            blockchain.add(new Block("Hey im the third block",blockchain.get(blockchain.size()-1).hash));
            
            String blockchainJson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(blockchain);      
            System.out.println(blockchainJson);  
    

        }
        //check blockchain's validity
        public static Boolean isChainValid() {
            Block currentBlock; 
            Block previousBlock;
            
            //loop through blockchain to check hashes:
            for(int i=1; i < blockchain.size(); i++) {
                currentBlock = blockchain.get(i);
                previousBlock = blockchain.get(i-1);
                //compare registered hash and calculated hash:
                if(!currentBlock.hash.equals(currentBlock.calculateHash()) ){
                    System.out.println("Current Hashes not equal");         
                    return false;
                }
                //compare previous hash and registered previous hash
                if(!previousBlock.hash.equals(currentBlock.previousHash) ) {
                    System.out.println("Previous Hashes not equal");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

here is my module-info.java. it is outside of the package blockchain

```
module noobChain {
    requires gson;
    requires java.sql;
}
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field public java.lang.String blockchain.Block.hash accessible: module noobChain does not "exports blockchain" to module gson
```

Any thoughts? I've imported the gson jar into my classpath in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

When you don't specify a custom `TypeAdapter`, Gson will use a reflection based adapter instead (which seems to be the case here). Therefore (as hinted by the exception message) you need to allow the Gson module to access your classes using reflection. You can either solve this by adding `exports blockchain to com.google.gson;` to your `module-info.java` file (as suggested by the exception message), or, because only runtime access is required for Gson, it suffices to use `opens blockchain to com.google.gson;`.

However, if you have a large number of packages which need to be accessible to Gson you can also open your complete module for runtime access to all modules by writing `open module noobChain { ... }`.

See also "[Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html)" for more information.

Some additional minor notes:

> `requires gson;`

Which Gson version are you using? Recent Gson versions are using the module name `com.google.gson` (see [source](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/0d9f6b677ae67cbd749ebca817139041d1977831/gson/src/main/java/module-info.java#L5)).

> `requires java.sql;`

Unless your code requires the `java.sql` module, you can remove this. Starting with Gson [2.8.9](https://github.com/google/gson/releases/tag/gson-parent-2.8.9) the dependency on the `java.sql` module is optional and Gson should work fine without it as well.